# A good approach in passing data back to presetingViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewController A, and on it, I modally presented a viewcontroller B, and now, B will navigate to C, then D, then E... And when I am done selecting the data on E, I am supposed to dismiss the stack of viewcontrollers (B, C, D, E) and pass a data back to A.

Currently, what I do is, I use chanin delegate... I set B as the delegate of A, then as we navigate through I set C as the delegate of B, then D as the delegate of C, then D as the delegate of E.. So when we are done with selecting an item on ViewController E, I call the delegate method which will trigger A to dismiss the entire viewControllers stack.

But I find this very troublesome approach..

I also used notification approach, but find it extremely inelegant..

So, I was wondering, if there is a better a approach in passing data back to A from E?

Thanks

Comment: are you using segues?  If so, simply use an unwind segue with the unwind method implemented in A. You can then get a reference to the A instance from the segue passed to `prepareForSegue` in E.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html for more information on segues. If you aren’t using segues, consider using segues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have always found this a pain in the ass, cuz I have always hated the delegate and notification centre approach.

Hmm, after I posted the question, I have thought of a solution I personally like.

So here is the implementation for those who are looking for an alternative.

what I do is that I subclass NavigationController.

```
    Class CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController {
       var onFinishedModelPresentation : (()-> Void)
}
```

then before anyone modal presents the navigationController, all you have do is this

```
    let newNavigationController = CustomNavigationController()
    newNavigationController.onFinishedVeriticalFlow = {
     (you can do whatever you want In this call back closure)
     self.navigationController.dismiss()
}
   self.navigationController.present(newNavigationController)
```

Then for viewControllers B, C, D , E, if any of them has a function to dismiss the entire viewControllers stack... All you have to do is call

```
self.navigationController.onFinishedVerticalFlow?()
```

The reason why I chose this approach over the delegates and notifications is beacause.

1. if we use delegate, in situations like what I have mentioned, will entail alot of delegate chaining, it makes the code extremely messy and hard to keep track.
2. if we use notification, we have to manually set up notifications on every view controllers and deal with removing the notification on every viewController.

Also, the reason I don't like notification is that it seems very decoupled... Like you know this particular notification will receive notification, but you have no idea who it may be from.. And if you remove the notification, it is hard to find out if there is still any notification.post that sends notification to this particular notifcation receiver. you would have manually search through the code and delete them .

But of course, most of these are my own reasons for coming up with this approach.. I just hope that it may help people who are looking for an alternative.

Cheers.

Comment: How about just get controller A from controller E and pass data to controller A ?